# Setting Winforms C# panel VerticalScroll.Value property to 0 is not having any effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue where my scrollbar for a panel on a usercontrol always appears at the bottom.

If I hover the mouse over the tab and cause the control to slide out and be shown, the scrollbar is at the bottom. If I then move the scrollbar to the top and move the mouse off the control (which causes it to hide again) and then move the mouse back over the tab (which causes the control to slide back out) the scroll bar is back at the bottom!

Setting the VerticalScroll.Value property on my panel to 0 is not having any effect - the control still shows at the bottom. Can someone tell me what events might fire when a control slides back into view on an autohide tab or just tell what I could do to solve this issue! I assume that the Paint event is what fires when the control is shown but I'm not entirely sure.

I did notice that in the VS designer that the scrollbar by default is shown at the bottom. Not sure whether this may have anything to do with the issue?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scrollingCtrl.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
scrollingCtrl.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: Figured it out. Adding the following at the end of the ctor for the user control (after InitialiseComponent()) did the trick:- panel1.Paint += (sender, args) =>
                          {
                              panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
                          };